# jquery select option value return null

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code:

```
$("#host_select").val($("#host_select option:first").val());
alert($("#host_select").val());
```

alerts null. But there are some options with values in host_select. What could be wrong?

Comment: code is huge. Everything works well except for this part.

Comment: just show your drop drown code ..

Comment: Data updated by json queries:<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <select class="form-control" id="host_select">
  </select>
</div>

Comment: where are the options ??? @VladimirAkkerman

Comment: If you have options your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/n9sxvet4/

Answer (score 4):

I guess, I found out. The thing is that you can't get selected value right after filling select input.

```
  $('#location_select').change(function()
         var sel=$("#location_select").val();
```

Here sel will be null. That's because at this moment browser still didn't make selection completely.
So I used setTimeout to wait selection to get completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do more research about javascript and html

here is an example:

https://fiddle.jshell.net/v4rwxz1q/

html:

```
<select name="" id="host_select">
  <option value="1">first</option>
  <option value="2">second</option>
</select>
```

js:

```
var first = $("option:first", "#host_select").val();
alert(first)
```

wish can let you have a good start

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var newOptions = {
            "Option 1": "value1",
            "Option 2": "value2",
            "Option 3": "value3"
        };

        var $el = $("#host_select");
        $el.empty(); // remove old options
        $.each(newOptions, function (value, key) {
            $el.append($("<option></option>")
               .attr("value", value).text(key));
        });


        // First
        $("#host_select").val($("#host_select option:first").val());

        alert($("#host_select").val());

        //Second
        $("#host_select").val($("#host_select option:eq(1)").val());

        alert($("#host_select").val());

        //third
        $("#host_select").val($("#host_select option:eq(2)").val());

        alert($("#host_select").val());

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <select class="form-control" id="host_select"></select>
</body>
</html>
```