# Triggering change with value from API

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a project where I need to obtain current coords, save them as variables, send those parameters to GeoNames and obtain country code.

That country code is meant to trigger a change event on a select dropdown menu (previously populated with country codes as values) which will show a border of the country (using geoJSON).

If I actually click on any country on the menu it works just fine, but I can't trigger the change after I get the code returned from GeoNames.

Whenever I add this line of code after I get the country code,

```
  $('#countrySelect').val('currCode').change();
```

I get this error:

Uncaught Error: Bounds are not valid.

```
at e.fitBounds (Map.js:291:10)

at Object.success (leaflet.js:47:11)

at i (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27151)

at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2:27914)

at z (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:12120)

at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:4:15680)
```

In my code, the error points to this line of code:  `map.fitBounds(border.getBounds());`

The error says "bounds are not valid", so I thought I was passing the wrong value and that it couldn't find the right bounds, but it seems like the value gets passed and then it can't associate the bounds to it? Which puzzles me as it works when I manually click on a country.

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? (I am using PHP to decode and I get the map from Leaflet).

The Leaflet code:

```
var map = L.map('map');
map.locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 17});
var OpenTopoMap = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17,
    attribution: 'Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://viewfinderpanoramas.org">SRTM</a> | Map style: &copy; <a href="https://opentopomap.org">OpenTopoMap</a> (<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>)'
}).addTo(map);
```

The code to populate the select:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "libs/php/geoJson.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",

    success: function(result) {
      //console.log(result);
      
      for (var i=0; i<result.data.border.features.length; i++) {
          $('#countrySelect').append($('<option>', {
              value: result.data.border.features[i].properties.iso_a3,
              text: result.data.border.features[i].properties.name,
              }));
         }
      }
  });
```

Code to create the border when country is manually selected (works):

```
var border;

$('#countrySelect').on("change", function() {
  let name = $('#countrySelect').val();
  //get + show border
 $.ajax({
     url: "libs/php/geoJson.php",
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(result) {
      const filterData = result.data.border.features.filter((a) => (a.properties.iso_a3 === name));
      border = L.geoJSON(filterData[0]).addTo(map); 
      map.fitBounds(border.getBounds());      
      },
  });
});
```

This is trying to get the coords (seems to be working), pass them to GeoNames to get country code (seems to be working too), and then trigger the above change event (which summons the error message, see above).

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

function success(position) {
let lat = position.coords.latitude;
let lng = position.coords.longitude;
let coords = {"lat": lat, "lng": lng};

// AJAX request with coords to geoNames to get country code

$.ajax({
  url: "libs/php/getCurrentCode.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  data: coords,

  success: function(result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
    if (result.status.name == "ok") {
      $(result["data"]["countryCode"]);
      let currCode = result.data;
      console.log(currCode);

  // trigger change with retrieved code

  $('#countrySelect').val('currCode').change();   
            };
    };
  });
};
```

My php:

```
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $executionStartTime = microtime(true);

    $url='http://api.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?&lat=' . $_REQUEST['lat'] . '&lng=' . $_REQUEST['lng'] . '&username=&style=full';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);

    $result=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    $decode = json_decode($result,true);    

    $output['status']['code'] = '200';
    $output['status']['name'] = 'ok';
    $output['status']['description'] = 'success';
    $output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . ' ms';
    $output['data'] = $decode['countryCode'];
    //var_dump($decode);        

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: You didn't share the code of Map.js:291, did you? What is your understanding of the error message? What part of it puzzles you most?

Comment: Are you using Leaflet?

Comment: @hakre Thank you, yes, I'm using Leaflet. I've now added that code too. The error says bounds are not valid, so I thought I was passing the wrong value and that it couldn't find the right bounds, but it seems like the value gets passed and then it can't associate the bounds to it? Which puzzles me as it works when I manually click on a country. The other thing that puzzles me is I see the current country code on the Console (so the request seems to go through), but if I go to Network and open the php file I get a warning of undefined array key for lat, lng and countryCode.

Comment: The errors in the network tab is because instead of POST request with those three parameters, you send GET request without them (they are missing then and the warning tells you which ones). / the other clarifications about the error and what puzzles you, you should add to the question, too, [edit] then in as within the comment they are quite lost. / And I still had problems to understand where the line of error is (Map.js:29). The error I'd say is from leaflet. Check Q&A with that error message on site, maybe you can spot something.

Comment: Check with `console.log(filterData[0]);` the outcome what you filter matches your expectations. It's just a guess, but if reading the name fails or is different than anticipated, then the filtering may result in unexpected or wrong data which then could trigger this error in leaflet.

Comment: Thank you, have updated my original post. I tried and I get "undefined", but, again, it works if I actually click on any country. I guess then the value doesn't get passed correctly?

Comment: Well, check that now, `console.log(name);` or similar. Just step back until you find the first place where it breaks.

Comment: And perhaps you can already start to write your answer, because it looks like that this is going to become your solution.

Comment: Hi, so, I've been trying what you suggested and it seems like the value doesn't get passed as if I console.log(name) when I force the select with that value I get "null", but if I don't force the select, I get the right value. The problem is, I don't know how to pass the value correctly?

Comment: Yes, as long as there is an unexpected value, we can wonder why is that so. Let's see again where name comes from... `let name = $('#countrySelect').val();`  - it _can_ return null, it's a jQuery thing. Test for null *before* the ajax call and return so the ajax is skipped. See if it helps, maybe there are multiple events, those with null you never want. also add console.log(name) then after the null-check if but before the ajax call so you can better inspect what happens already before you pinch it to ajax.

Comment: So, it seems to be working now but only on first load. If I re-load it I get the same error. I'll keep investigating...

Comment: A user mentioned this workaround: _"So I used setTimeout to wait selection to get completed."_ [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35217475/367456) unfortunately without any example for that. Any chance the select is disabled? jQuery bugtracker mentions that null should be returned if an option (or the select?) is disabled.